# cxf webclient - exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is Status : 406

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I am getting following error(406) while using CXF webclient, but when I use URL api, i am getting expected output.

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/assignment] is completed
http://localhost:8080/assignment/cxf/login/test/test1
Result--><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><user>    <userName>test</userName>    <firstName>Mike</firstName>    <lastName>Tom</lastName></user>
Aug 02, 2013 11:20:31 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils findTargetMethod
WARNING: No operation matching request path "/assignment/cxf/login/test/test1" is found, Relative Path: /login/test/test1, HTTP Method: GET, ContentType: */*, Accept: application/xml,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
Aug 02, 2013 11:20:31 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: WebApplicationException has been caught : no cause is available
Aug 02, 2013 11:20:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/assignment] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is Status : 406
Headers : 
Date : Sat, 03 Aug 2013 04:20:31 GMT
Content-Length : 0
Server : Apache-Coyote/1.1
] with root cause
Status : 406
Headers : 
Date : Sat, 03 Aug 2013 04:20:31 GMT
Content-Length : 0
Server : Apache-Coyote/1.1

    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:680)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:421)
    at com.viasat.test.login.servlet.LoginServlet.processLogin(LoginServlet.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

My client code is:

```
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/assignment/cxf/login/"+name+"/"+password);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            res.append(output);
        }
        System.out.println("Result-->"+res.toString());
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/assignment/cxf/login/"+name+"/"+password);            
    //  WebClient t = webClient.path("");
        String res = webClient.accept("text/xml").get(String.class);
        System.out.println("=============="+res);
```

Rest endpoint Service class:

```
@GET
    @Path("/login/{userName}/{password}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    public String userLogin(@PathParam("userName")String username, @PathParam("password")String password)
            throws JAXBException, PropertyException, FileNotFoundException {
```

**Question**

1) What changes I need to make, to fix the error

2) To return as Json, what changes I need to make? If I write, conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");I am getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

client side changes:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/assignment/cxf/login/test/test1");            
String res = webClient.accept("application/xml").get(String.class);
```

here instead of `String res = webClient.accept("text/xml").get(String.class);` made

```
 String res = webClient.accept("application/xml").get(String.class);
```

Service class changes:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/login/{userName}/{password}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public String userLogin(@PathParam("userName")String username, @PathParam("password")String password)
```

changed `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` in userLogin method instead of `MediaType.TEXT_XML`

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTTP spec, a 406 response means that the server cannot meet the requirements as set out in the request's ACCEPT headers.  However, the server-side log messages seem to be implying that something else is happening.

I suggest that you do what the log message suggests.  Enable debug logging and see what the fine-grained log messages say about what is going wrong.